# unable to infer compiler target triple for clang

Tags: makefile, clang, llvm

I have modified the clang. It was working properly. But then I had some git related issues so I cleaned the git and checked out again. Now when I try to run `make clean` in clang I am getting the following error. How can I fix this?

```
#A set of warnings here
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/test/llvm/projects/compiler-rt'
make/platform/clang_linux.mk:16: *** "unable to infer compiler target triple for clang".  Stop.
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/test/llvm/projects/compiler-rt'
make[4]: *** [CleanRuntimeLibraries] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/test/llvm/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt'
make[3]: *** [compiler-rt/.makeclean] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/test/llvm/tools/clang/runtime'
make[2]: *** [clean] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/llvm/tools/clang'
make[1]: *** [clang/.makeclean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/test/llvm/tools'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Comment: I even tried to check out the new clang, its showing the same error

Comment: Is there a configure script which is to be run before make?

Comment: Use CMake, it has automatic reconfiguration feature.

Comment: @mishr I ran configure. Still it is showing the same

Comment: Try building the the whole llvm again at the root dir.

Comment: @mishr This error occurred when building the whole llvm. I also tried just building clang. Finally I made all the changes to a new llvm and tried. Now its working. But when I clone llvm from my git (modified llvm), its not working. I am checking why is this happening

Comment: @mishr In the git version I was able to fix the problem of installation. It was not this error but something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and solved it. My problem was the link for clang failed (error 9) because I didn't have enough memory. It needs about 4 gig of memory to link, and I only had 3.5 total real memory and swap available.

Look just before these errors and possibly, you'll see that the link for clang failed.
ls the clang executable at {your build directory}/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang mine was zero bytes (because of link failure).

It then generated the "unable to infer compiler target triple" because it didn't have a clang to execute.

My solution was to create a swap file (because I didn't have any space to expand my swap partition) following the instructions at [geek swap definition](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable correctly. At first, I set it without the lib64.

I installed llvm on my `$HOME/local` so, the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would be.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH”:$HOME/local/lib:$HOME/local/lib64
```